# Does PyTorch's nn.DataParallel load the same model in each GPU?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, multi-gpu

The only way it would seem to work (logically) is if the model was loaded in each of the GPUs. This would mean that when weights are updated, each GPU would need to update the weights as well, increasing the workload compared to a single GPU. Is this line of reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [it is advised](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/cuda.html#use-nn-parallel-distributeddataparallel-instead-of-multiprocessing-or-nn-dataparallel) to use [`torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html#torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel) instead.

You can check [`torch.nn.DataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html) documentation where the process is described (you can also check [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.html#DataParallel) and dig a little deeper on [github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch), [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/parallel/replicate.py) is how replication of module is performed).

Here is roughly how it's done:

### Initialization

All (or chosen) devices ids are saved in constructor and dimension along which data will be scattered (almost always `0` meaning it will be splitted to devices along batch)

### Forward

This is done during every `forward` run:

1. Inputs are scattered (tensors along dimensions, `tuple`, `list`, `dict` shallowed copied, other data is shared among threads).
2. If there is only one device just return `module(*args, **kwargs)`
3. If there are multiple devices, copy the network from source machine to other devices (it is done each time!)
4. Run forward on each device with it's respective input
5. Gather outputs from devices onto a single source device (concatenation of outputs) onto a source machine.
6. Run the rest of the code, backprop, update weights on source machine etc.

Source machine is the `cuda:0` by default, but it can be chosen. Also weights are updated on a single `device`, only batch is scattered and the outputs gathered.